# Using BlinkPlanner in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I was reading the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/common.html) about how to use the "BlinkPlanner" and I found that it is possible to create an instance of **TableEnvironmentImpl** using the code above:

```
import org.apache.flink.table.api.{EnvironmentSettings, TableEnvironment}

val bbSettings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().useBlinkPlanner().inBatchMode().build()
val bbTableEnv = TableEnvironment.create(bbSettings)
```

Would it be possible to create an instance of **BatchTableEnviromentImpl** which uses "BlinkPlanner" as well? I prefer to use **BatchTableEnviroment** because it exposes more methods than the standard implementation, like for example **toDataSet**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible to use `BlinkPlanner` with `BatchTableEnvironment`.

Blink planner works only with the `DataStream` api both for batch and streaming. Actually the plan is to deprecate the `DataSet` entirely. There are plans to have an equivalent of `BatchTableEnvironment` that will have methods like e.g. `toBoundedStream`. The earliest possible release when we could add it is 1.11 though.